# Display iFrame url in address bar

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe, address-bar

Is it possible to include the url of the iframe content in the url address bar?

For example, i have a domain `sub.test.com` which has an iframe with src to `realpage.com`

Surfing through the page logically doesnt change anything in the address bar since we are opening the realpage in the iframe on other domain.

I know it is not possible to inject the whole url into address bar, but what about without the hostname?

For example, if i open site `realpage.com/first.php` in `iframe`, i want the url in address bar to change to `sub.test.com/first.php` or `sub.test.com/first`

Comment: Check out the following link for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here you can either use `pushState` ([more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)) or you can use Hash key navigation ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252770/how-to-implement-a-hash-key-navigation)) if you wish to make it compatible with browsers that do not yet have `pushState` available.

pushState example:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

Hash Key example:

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) {  
  alert("The browser supports the hashchange event!");  
}  

function locationHashChanged() {  
  if (location.hash === "#somecoolfeature") {  
    somecoolfeature();  
  }  
}  

window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```

For more info here is another link: [Change the URL in the browser without loading the new page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The top level frame can change the address (although not the origin parts) with [the history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), see `pushState` in particular.

To do this in reaction to navigation in the frame, since it is across origins, you'd need to use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to send the URL you want to change it to.